# Kotlin reflection

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

With `Retrofit`, I am fetching data and getting `JSONObject` with the structure like this for example:

```
{
    "token": "some-token",
    "tiles": [
        {
            "id": "id-1",
            "type": "RedTile",
            "title": "This red title",
            "stuff": "hello world"
        },
        {
            "id": "id-2",
            "type": "BlueTile",
            "title": "This blue title",
            "value": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I get this response, I need to make a parser that will actually take the type from every tile and match it with the class that already exists inside application. I need to basically from this response to create new one with token and tiles list but in this case tiles will reflect to actual class in app.

Any idea what is proper way to do it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you mention Reflection in your question's title:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

data class TileResponse(val id: String, val type: String, val title: String, val stuff: String? = null, val value: Int? = null)
data class Response(val token: String, val tiles: List<Tile>)

sealed interface Tile
data class RedTile(val title: String, val stuff: String) : Tile
data class BlueTile(val title: String, val value: Int) : Tile

fun getTiles(): List<Tile> {
  return tileResponses
    .filter { tileResponse -> mapTypeToClass.containsKey(tileResponse.type) }
    .map { tileResponse ->
      val clazz = mapTypeToClass[tileResponse.type]!!
      val constructor = clazz.constructors.first()
      val declaredMemberProperties = tileResponse::class.declaredMemberProperties
      val fields = constructor.parameters.map { parameter ->
        parameter to declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == parameter.name }
      }
      val arguments = fields.associate { (parameter, property) ->
        parameter to property.call(tileResponse)
      }
      constructor.callBy(arguments)
    }
}

val tileResponses = listOf(
  TileResponse("id-1", "RedTile", "This red title", "hello world", null),
  TileResponse("id-2", "BlueTile", "This blue title", "null", 200)
)

val mapTypeToClass = mapOf(
  "RedTile" to RedTile::class,
  "BlueTile" to BlueTile::class,
)

val response = Response("some-token", getTiles())
```

Comment: Thx a lot man this is basically what I need. Thx one more time!

Comment: Generally reflection is to be avoided if possible. And if you use reflection, I would advise to build a serious test suite around it. In the above code there are several problems which can occur at runtime: For example _declaredMemberProperties.first { ... }_ would crash if no names match. This could be because of spelling mistakes. It could also be because of namespaces, etc.

Comment: Ok but what is other way to do it dynamically? I must parse array and based on type match correct class and create object and then put that object in new list. What alternatives actually I have?

Comment: See @IvoBeckers' answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your classes look like, but suppose it's this for example:

```
sealed interface Tile
data class RedTile(val title: String, val stuff: String) : Tile
data class BlueTile(val title: String, val value: Int) : Tile
```

Then you could make this as response object

```
data class Response (
    val token: String,
    val tiles: List<TileResponse>
) {
    fun getTilesObjects() = tiles.mapNotNull { it.toTile() }
}

data class TileResponse (
    val id: String,
    val type: String,
    val title: String,
    val stuff: String? = null,
    val value: Int? = null
){
    fun toTile() : Tile? {
        if (type == "RedTile" && stuff != null) return RedTile(title, stuff)
        if (type == "BlueTile" && value != null) return BlueTile(title, value)
        return null
    }
}
```

And then you can call `toTile()` on the individual `TileResponse` objects or get the full list by doing `getTilesObjects()` on the response object

Comment: Yeah but with this solution I will finish in large if else probably. I want to make it more dynamic so that I can match class at runtime , create object from that class and return new tiles array.